# How to allow the user to change the value in the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

In case 1, I will search for the Employee No and the output will be Employe Name, Number, Salary and etc. And next is I will Edit the salary. How can I replace the value in the `ArrayList` ? If I edit the salary in the Case 1 the salary in Case 2 must be replace with the value I input in the Case 1 Edit Salary

```
String EmpName[]=new String [d];
Integer EmpNo[]=new Integer[d];
int Salary[]=new int[d];
int r=0, number, payment;
char menu;
String display, name;

System.out.print("Enter Number of Records: ");
r = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

for(i=0; i<r;i++){
    System.out.print("\nEnter Employee Number: ");
    EmpNo[i]=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    System.out.print("Enter Employee Name: ");
    EmpName[i]=reader.readLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Salary: ");
    Salary[i]=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
}
do {
    System.out.println("\n\nDisplay Menu");
    System.out.println("1.Edit Salary\n2.Display Employee Record\n3.Salary\n4.Exit Program");
    System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
    a=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

    switch(a){
        case 1:
            System.out.print("\nEnter Employee Number: ");
            number = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            int y = Arrays.asList(EmpNo).indexOf(number);
            if(Arrays.asList(EmpNo).contains(number)){
                System.out.println("\nEmployee Number: "+EmpNo[y]+" \nEmployee Name: "+EmpName[y]+" \nSalary: "+Salary[y]+"");
                System.out.print("\nEnter New Salary!: ");
                //How can I replace the value in the Salary and the value must replace in the Case 2 too.
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Employee Number not Found!!");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
              System.out.print("\nEnter Employee Number: ");
              number = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
              int x = Arrays.asList(EmpNo).indexOf(number);
              if(Arrays.asList(EmpNo).contains(number)){
                  if(Salary[x]<4999)
                     System.out.print(+decimal.format(Salary[x]-Salary[x]*0.2+Salary[x]*0.3)+);
                        else if(Salary[x]>5000  && Salary[x]<9999)
                        System.out.print(+decimal.format(Salary[x]-Salary[x]*0.10+Salary[x]*0.5)+);
                        else if(Salary[x]>10000 && Salary[x]<19999)
                        System.out.print(+decimal.format(Salary[x]-Salary[x]*0.15+Salary[x]*0.7)+);
                        else if(Salary[x]>20000)
                        System.out.print(+decimal.format(Salary[x]-Salary[x]*0.20+Salary[x]*0.9)+);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Name not Found!!");
                }
                break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same array list to store and retrieve a salary, and if you modify it, the other cases will notice the change since the array list is in scope for them. Therefore you just need to modify the array list containing the salary.

Comment: can you show me how to do it ? im kinda new in java

Comment: Actually, when I was looking through your code, all you need to do is to take the employee number and store it as a variable. The, that index number should correspond to the location of the salary value in the array salary that you want to change. So you just need to modify the array salary at the index of the employee number like this: Salary[indexOfEmployeeSalarythatyouwanttochange] = new_salary.

Comment: Yes. Make sure you get the employee number as the index of the salary array

Comment: the Salary[]= new_salary  does it have a underscore ?

Comment: The new salary is the new amount of money you want to keep in. It can be any variable or can simple be a value.

Comment: so it will be like this Salary[i] = new Salary ??

Comment: No. It will be like this Salary[i] = amount, where amount is a variable that stores a value like 50. You only use the new keyword when you create objects

Answer (score 0):

However your question is quite not clear. But if you want to change a particular value in an ArrayList then you can do so by using it's index.

`listName.set(int index, E newElement)`

[More info](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29)

Answer (score 0):

The continual use of creating an ArrayList is not efficient,

```
 int y = Arrays.asList(EmpNo).indexOf(number);
```

so create the List just once

```
 ArrayList al = Arrays.asList(EmpNo);
```

to get the item do

```
 emp = al.get (index);
```

to set it

```
al.set (index, newEmp);
```

In you case it would be beter to create a class `Emp` to contain the empId, empname, and salary

Then you List could be a list of Employees, not three arrays of empId, empname, and salary

```
ArrayList <Employee> al = new ArrayList <Employee> ();

Employee emp = new Employee (....);
al.add (emp);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList()` creates an List backed by the originally provided array. So if you make changes in the array/list, the changes are reflected the other side. So just modify the array directly.

Comment: can you show me how to do it ? im kinda new in java

Comment: String[] array = new String[]{"A","B", "C", "D"};
List<String> lst = Arrays.asList(array);

array[0] = "a";
System.out.println(lst.get(0)); //prints a

lst.set(1, "b");
System.out.println(array[1]); // prints b